# CMake re links libraries which dependencies where already included in a library

Tags: c++, cmake, build, ninja

CMake re-links libraries to executable which dependencies where already included in a linked library. This library is dependent of several libraries which are loaded from vcpkg installation. So the build result ends up having duplicated code.

The thing is that when only the library target is built it generates a single clean static library containing all dependencies. But when executable gets built it also links the dependencies of the library as dynamic .dll libs, so it ends up being compiled the static library, and the executable linking the static library but also all dependencies dynamically.

The main library has this structure:

```
MyLibd.lib( libA.lib, libB.lib, libC.lib )
```

And the project has all its targets in a single CMakeLists.txt file for now.

Below there's the makefile output produced by Ninja for the executable. As far as I understand It links the libraries and then it re-links(?) them again. Also the .dll files aren't mentioned anyway in the entire file.

```
#############################################
# Link the executable App.exe

build App.exe: CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER__App_Debug CMakeFiles\App.dir\app\App.cpp.obj | MyLibd.lib C$:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libA.lib  C$:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libB.lib C$:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libC.lib || MyLibd.lib
  FLAGS = /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  LINK_FLAGS = /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
  LINK_LIBRARIES = MyLibd.lib  C:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libA.lib   C:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libB.lib  C:\Users\...\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libC.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\App.dir
  POST_BUILD = cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\...\build\x64-debug && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/Users/.../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary C:/Users/.../build/x64-debug/App.exe -installedDir C:/Users/.../vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out"
  PRE_LINK = cd .
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = CMakeFiles\App.dir\
  TARGET_FILE = App.exe
  TARGET_IMPLIB = App.lib
  TARGET_PDB = App.pdb


#############################################
```

CMake for the exe target:

```
# App
project(App VERSION 0.1 DESCRIPTION "App project")

add_executable(App)

set_property(TARGET App PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

target_sources(App
    PRIVATE
        app/App.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(App MyLib)

include_directories(${DEPENDENCY_INCLUDE_DIR})
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Configure presets:

```
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "windows-base",
            "generator": "Ninja",
            "hidden": true,
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
            "installDir": "${sourceDir}/install/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl"
            },
            "condition": {
                "type": "equals",
                "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
                "rhs": "Windows"
            },
            "toolchainFile": "${sourceDir}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        },
        {
            "name": "x64-debug",
            "displayName": "x64 Debug",
            "inherits": "windows-base",
            "architecture": {
                "value": "x64",
                "strategy": "external"
            },
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "x64-release",
            "displayName": "x64 Release",
            "inherits": "windows-base",
            "architecture": {
                "value": "x64",
                "strategy": "external"
            },
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I've used Ninja and VS generators and both have the same result. And I also checked that the dlls are really linked removing one and running the exe, which produces dll not found error.

Do you know how to solve this for building only an exe linking the static MyLibd.lib library ?

Comment: With the current state of the question post, all we know is that your executable is linked with `MyLib` target, but we don't know what this target means. Please, add to the question post the **complete project** (in form of [mcve]). Also include **exact error message** you got.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.